# Lists<List<Double>>adding to HashMap

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

So, after request of compiling code, here it is. And the problem is that after adding second Hash element Called "B", the output messes up.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, List<List<Double>>> alphabet = new HashMap<String,List<List<Double>>>();
        List<List<Double>> something = new ArrayList<List<Double>>();
        List<Double> stuffList = new ArrayList<Double>();
        stuffList.add(3.1);
        stuffList.add(3.2);
        stuffList.add(3.3);
        something.add(stuffList);
        alphabet.put("A", something);
        System.out.println(something);
        System.out.println(alphabet);
        stuffList.clear();
        something.clear();
        stuffList.add(3.4);
        something.add(stuffList);
        alphabet.put("B", something);
        System.out.println(something);
        System.out.println(alphabet);
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
[[3.1, 3.2, 3.3]]
{A=[[3.1, 3.2, 3.3]]}
[[3.4]]
{A=[[3.4]], B=[[3.4]]}
```

Which in my opinion and needs, should be:

```
[[3.1, 3.2, 3.3]]
{A=[[3.1, 3.2, 3.3]]}
[[3.4]]
{A=[[3.1, 3.2, 3.3]], B=[[3.4]]}
```

Comment: How can you add a `String` in a List that contains only `Double` ?

Comment: Read up on the difference between "by reference" and "by value".

Comment: @JamesMontagne i should've done that. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are still referencing old instances of the lists. This should work as expected:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, List<List<Double>>> alphabet = new HashMap<String,List<List<Double>>>();
        List<List<Double>> something = new ArrayList<List<Double>>();
        List<Double> stuffList = new ArrayList<Double>();
        stuffList.add(3.1);
        stuffList.add(3.2);
        stuffList.add(3.3);
        something.add(stuffList);
        alphabet.put("A", something);
        System.out.println(something);
        System.out.println(alphabet);
        // Create new instances:
        something = new ArrayList<List<Double>>();
        stuffList = new ArrayList<Double>();
        stuffList.add(3.4);
        something.add(stuffList);
        alphabet.put("B", something);
        System.out.println(something);
        System.out.println(alphabet);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Java objects are always taken by reference.
Which means that

```
stuffList.clear();
something.clear();
stuffList.add(3.4);
```

operates on the same lists you put in the map by the key "A".

So in the end the map contains the same list twice.